# Create a column on the last row of the group that places the first row of group in first column and second in second column...etc using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table where there are multiple entries for the same instance and multiple calls made to that instance.  I am trying to create a column for each call where the last call has a column for each row starting from the first call.  Here is an example table:

| Name | Discharge Date | Recorded Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 7/1/2021 | 7/2/2021 13:20 |
| A | 7/1/2021 | 7/3/2021 8:45 |
| A | 7/15/2021 | 7/15/2021 9:00 |
| A | 7/15/2021 | 7/15/2021 11:32 |
| A | 7/15/2021 | 7/15/2021 14:14 |
| A | 7/20/2021 | 7/21/2021 10:02 |
| B | 7/3/2021 | 7/4/2021 11:46 |
| B | 7/6/2021 | 7/7/2021 9:34 |
| B | 7/6/2021 | 7/7/2021 12:23 |
| B | 7/6/2021 | 7/8/2021 8:58 |
| B | 7/6/2021 | 7/8/2021 15:51 |
| B | 7/29/2021 | 7/30/2021 11:12 |
| B | 7/29/2021 | 7/30/2021 16:41 |

I am basically trying to get it to look like this:

| Name | Discharge Date | Recorded Time | Call 1 | Call 2 | Call 3 | Call 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 7/1/2021 | 7/3/2021 8:45 | 7/2/2021 13:20 | 7/3/2021 8:45 |  |  |
| A | 7/15/2021 | 7/15/2021 14:14 | 7/15/2021 9:00 | 7/15/2021 11:32 | 7/15/2021 14:14 |  |
| A | 7/20/2021 | 7/21/2021 10:02 | 7/21/2021 10:02 |  |  |  |
| B | 7/3/2021 | 7/4/2021 11:46 | 7/4/2021 11:46 |  |  |  |
| B | 7/6/2021 | 7/8/2021 15:51 | 7/7/2021 9:34 | 7/7/2021 12:23 | 7/8/2021 8:58 | 7/8/2021 15:51 |
| B | 7/29/2021 | 7/30/2021 16:41 | 7/30/2021 11:12 | 7/30/2021 16:41 |  |  |

I've tried doing shift

```
df1['Call 1'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'])['RECORDED_TIME'].shift(-1)
df1['Call 2'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'])['RECORDED_TIME'].shift(-2)
df1['Call 3'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'])['RECORDED_TIME'].shift(-3)
df1['Call 4'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'])['RECORDED_TIME'].shift(-4)
```

Which gives me the last row backwards.  I've tried doing nth such as:

```
df1['Call 1'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'], as_index=False)['RECORDED_TIME'].nth(0)
df1['Call 2'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'], as_index=False)['RECORDED_TIME'].nth(1)
df1['Call 3'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'], as_index=False)['RECORDED_TIME'].nth(2)
df1['Call 4'] = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Discharge Date'], as_index=False)['RECORDED_TIME'].nth(3)
```

I've tried changing the position numbers and they don't loop around.  So I can't seem to catch call 1 from the first call made within that group of calls.  To reiterate I am trying to create a column on the last call of the group that places the first call in column call 1, second call in column call 2, etc.  Dropping the other calls and keeping the last call under recorded time is easy once I can get those new columns in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
gb = df.groupby(["Name", "Discharge Date"])["Recorded Time"]
result = pd.concat([gb.last(), 
                    pd.DataFrame(gb.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack()).add_prefix("Call ")], 
                   axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked really well as well and did not have any issues not keeping name and discharge date as index, just adding as_index=False to the groupby solved that issue.  Still have the same issue of the code removing the other columns in the real code.  Both of these codes they are very well written, and the reality is that I can go back and join this to the original code and drop the unnecessary rows, just wondering if using this same code (with some modifications)  I can keep all the original columns as well.  This already dropped the rows that were not necessary.

Comment: If you want to keep the other columns, you will likely have to use a `pd.merge`.

Comment: I figured about as much.  Which was what I did and it works perfect that way.  I was just wondering.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's always how I have had to keep original columns after `groupby`. Not saying there isn't a better way, but I'm unaware if there is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gc = ['Name','Discharge Date']
rc = df.groupby(gc)['Recorded Time'].last()

(df.assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby(gc).cumcount())
 .set_index(gc + ['cc'])['Recorded Time'].unstack()
 .rename(lambda x: 'Call {}'.format(x+1),axis=1).join(rc))
```

Comment: This works really well.  Having issues trying not having name and discharge date becoming an index.  Also while the sample doesn't have any additional columns the original does as well and after running it deletes all other columns.  Tried adding as_index=False to the groupby but got an error message.

Comment: you could add `reset_index()` to the end.